# htaccess rewrite : Wordpress directory + subdomain redirect not working together

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, directory, subdomain

I moved a Wordpress blog from blog.mywebsite.com to mywebsite.com/blog/ .

Everything was OK until I tried to redirect old links to the new location.

I want people asking http://blog.mywebsite.com/2014/09/article-example/ to find themselves in http://mywebsite.com/blog/2014/09/article-example/

But the htaccess is already completed with some rules using the keyword "blog"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```

I cannot find the way to write the rule

Today I have an error 500 with this link : http://blog.mywebsite.com/2014/09/article-example/

I would like at least to redirect to  mywebsite.com/blog/  , ideally to http://mywebsite.com/blog/2014/09/article-example/

Any idea?

Thanks and good day everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your current htaccess code by this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/blog/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I adjusted the rule with 
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/blog/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
and it works like a charm :)
Thank you very much :)